# IOS : Move an image with a timer

Tags: ios, image, move, fluid

Hi, I have a problem, when I click on a button.

I would a timer which stop my code for several milliseconds to create a fluid's movement.

This is my code :

```
- (IBAction)goRight:(id)sender {
    sprite.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sprite_rr.png"];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    sprite.center = CGPointMake(sprite.center.x + 5, sprite.center.y);
    sprite.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sprite_lr.png"];
}
```

But this code patient 30 milliseconds then execute directly without waiting.

Can you help me please ?
Thanks

PS : Sorry for my bad English ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
- (IBAction)goRight:(id)sender {
    sprite.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sprite_rr.png"];
    CGRect frame = sprite.frame;
    frame.origin.x += 5;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            [sprite setFrame: frame];
            sprite.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sprite_lr.png"];
        }];

}
```

In order to animate or "move" objects visually, you need to use `animateWithDuration: animations:` method.

Edit: Try setting the frame instead of modifying the center.

Comment: Thanks, but the image is the same, no change :/

Comment: I edited my answer, try it now. Usually to set the new frame is a pain

Comment: Sorry I'm a new developer on iOS, and when I write "frame.point.x" there is an error. The IDE says to use frame.size or frame.origin

Comment: sorry, `frame.origin.x`

Answer (score 0):

Bad practice to use `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];`. This stops everything that is running on the main thread. When this line of code is reached the main thread is blocked for the time you have specified, then the rest of your code will be executed. Keep in mind that while you are blocking your thread your app will freeze as all User interface updates are done on this tread and can't be performed. Avoid using this unless you have a reason for that.

Without providing more code, or example of what exactly you want to stop while animating your `UIImageView` I don't think we could help further.

Answer (score 0):

You might use something along the lines of:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1
                      delay: 0.03 // delays the animation for however long you set. This is 30 ms.
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations: ^{
                     [sprite setFrame:CGRectMake(sprite.frame.origin.x+5, sprite.frame.origin.y, sprite.frame.size.width, sprite.frame.size.height)];
                 }
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Comment: Thanks, but the image is the same, no change :/